# sRGB to RGB color conversion

Tags: java

I have sRGB numbers stored in file produced by Color.getRGB() method like this :

```
//example for RED color
int num = Color.RED.getRGB(); // num is -65536 for RED
// save num to a file.
```

Now I have to read the values from that file and have to convert each number to `[x,y,z]` RGB format. From `-65536` I need to get `[255,51,51]`.

Can anyone tell me how to do that in java?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that I have checked the documentation of Color object but could not find anything which would convert the num backwards

Comment: How is `-65536`obtained from `[255,51,51]` ?

Comment: It's obtained from Color.RED.getRGB() method then stored in file. I need to read that value from file and transfer it to [x,y,z] RGB format. In the case of RED color from `-65536` i need to get [255,51,51]

Comment: 1st. Color.RED represents the color [255, 0, 0] not [255, 51, 51].
2nd. @vincrichaud The number you get from .getRGB is negative because it returns an int and the class Color stores sRGB as 8 bit per channel RGBA which is a total of 32 bits and since the int type is signed it can only represent 31 bit positive numbers. So the .getRGB function returns an overflowed int for every Color with an alpha bigger than 127.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is

```
int num = Color.RED.getRGB();
int blue =  num & 255;
int green = (num >> 8) & 255;
int red =   (num >> 16) & 255;
System.out.println("R:"+red+"\n"+"G:"+green+"\n"+"B:"+blue);
```

Comment: You should prefer the use of standard library functions over writing your own code. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Color color = new Color(-65536);
int r = color.getRed();
int g = color.getGreen();
int b = color.getBlue();

System.out.println(String.format("%d %d %d", r, g, b));  // 255 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), there is method in the Color class to obtain this

```
getRed()
getGreen()
getBleu()
```